# uint16 conversion issue

Tags: solidity, ether, data-types, type-casting, typescript

So I want to test this Solidity code using Typescript but faced with a type conversion issue.

```
uint16 base;

function addNumberToBase(uint16 number_) {
    // This number must be between 1 ~ 5
    require(number_ < 1 && number_ >= 5, "This number must be between 1 ~ 5");
    base += number_;
}
```

And here is the TS testing code, I tried here many types but didn't work.

```
it("Should add a number between 1 ~ 5 to base", async () => {
     const number_ : Number = 4;
     await contract.addNumberToBase(number_); 

     // But here getting this error: 
     // Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert This number must be between 1~5
});
```

The same with using types **Uint16Array** and **BigNumberish**.

My suggestion is that's because of an issue in converting between types in both languages. So, please are there any useful libraries for converting **uint16**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
require(number_ < 1 && number_ >= 5, "This number must be between 1 ~ 5");
```

This is an impossibility.

It should say:

```
require(number_ >= 1 && number_ <= 5, "This number must be between 1 ~ 5");
```

I'm not 100% if you will get a JavaScript number or a BigNumber since `uint16` can be handled by JavaScript. It's *always* BigNumber for `uint256` types that are too big for JavaScript native types.

If the returned value looks like a weird object, use `toString(10)` to parse it, e.g. `var value = parseInt(response.toString(10));`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice answer! I wonder what could be an unwanted side effect of using `toString()` instead of `toString(10)`?

Comment: The `10` bit means to use "base10" (decimal) for interpretation of the value.

Comment: Thanks so much, the error has been solved, it was a logical error from the contract itself. 

Answer (score 1):

The first paramter in `require` must be `true` for it to continue. Currently, your code checks for a number that is smaller than 1, and larger than or equal to 5. If you change the `require` call to the following, it should work:

```
require(number >= 1 && number <= 5, "This number must be between 1 - 5");
```

This is not an issue with converting numbers to `uint16`, as Web3.js and Ethers.js can do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much, the error has been solved, it was a logical error from the contract itself. 